# How to run the Power Shell scripts from Automation Anywhere in Citrix?

Tags: powershell, automation, sqlanywhere

Any answers will related Automation Anywhere from PowerShell are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If AA itself is installed in citrix then it should not be a problem you can call any type of script via AA from scripts menu from AA home.

But if AA is installed outside citrix, You need to rely on Screen Scraping / Image Recognizer.